# Rust union usage features

Tags: rust

I am working on my university homework.
The task is to sort data in structure with variant field (union).
We usually use C, but I decided to try Rust and faced a problem/
I can't understand how to fix my errors.
One of structs inside union must include string.
As far as I understood the problem is in this String.
My structure:

```
pub struct Show
{
    theatre: String,
    name: String,
    director: String,
    price_min: i64,
    price_max: i64,
    type_name: ShowType,
    type_data: ShowTypeData,
}
enum ShowType
{
    Childish,
    Adultish,
    Musical,
}
union ShowTypeData
{
    childish: ChildishShow,
    adultish: AdultishShow,
    musical: MusicalShow,
}
struct ChildishShow
{
    age_target: i8,
    subtype: ChildishShowType,
}
enum ChildishShowType
{
    Tale,
    Piece,
}
struct AdultishShow
{
    subtype: AdultishShowType,
}
enum AdultishShowType
{
    Piece,
    Dramma,
    Comedy,
}
struct MusicalShow
{
    composer: String,
    country: String,
    age_min: i8,
    duration: i16,
}
```

Errors:

```
error[E0658]: unions with non-`Copy` fields are unstable
--> src/show.rs:19:1
   |
19 | / union ShowTypeData
20 | | {
21 | |     childish: ChildishShow,
22 | |     adultish: AdultishShow,
23 | |     musical: MusicalShow,
24 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: see issue #55149 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55149> for more information
error[E0740]: unions may not contain fields that need dropping
  --> src/show.rs:23:5
   |
23 |     musical: MusicalShow,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: `std::mem::ManuallyDrop` can be used to wrap the type
  --> src/show.rs:23:5
   |
23 |     musical: MusicalShow,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I didn't understand what "Copy" and "Drop" mean exactly.
Probably that is my problem.

Comment: Please construct a proper [mre]. The given code is incomplete, making it hard for us to reproduce the exact problem presented.

Comment: You might want to reconsider whether you _really_ want a `union` there, or just a single `enum` instead. Note that `enum`s in Rust are actually sum types, more powerful than enums in C. See [chapter 6](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-00-enums.html) of the book for more about enums.

Comment: The errors look very clear to me. Unions are very limited. Are you unsure what "drop" means? Are you unsure what "Copy" means?

Comment: "I learned C before" there's your problem. `union` is a very low-level and unsafe type which exists *only to strictly replicate C unions*, **`union` should not be used unless you have no other choice**. `Show` should most likely be an enum of the underlying possibilities, but you don't provide the depth or breadth of information to really help.

Comment: @E_net4hasmanyfriends I edited the code. Is it enough now? I am not sure, but as far as I know, enum stores memory for every enumerator inside it. In the same time union doesn't.

Comment: @kmdreko yes, I am.

Comment: @ДаниилСкотников The code is still incomplete. And no, enums do not allocate memory for all variants at once, but enough for the largest variant and the variant discriminator.

Comment: @E_net4hasmanyfriends That is all i wrote. What else is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not copy unions from C to Rust verbatim.

Write instead:

```
pub struct Show
{
    theatre: String,
    name: String,
    director: String,
    price_min: i64,
    price_max: i64,
    show_type: ShowType,
}
enum ShowType
{
    Childish(ChildishShow),
    Adultish(AdultishShow),
    Musical(MusicalShow),
}
```

Unions are a low-level, intrinsically unsafe construct in Rust, and quite limited about what you can put in. Use an `enum` instead when possible. No unions, no problems.

Comment: What about memory efficiency? In C I have to use union because it stored memory only for a single field. Is it same for enums in Rust?

Comment: Yes, it is the same, but better. Your `ShowType` will contain the discriminant and the corresponding data. The advantage is that you won't be able to access the wrong data.